# SQL Server OPENROWSET not pulling JSON Data

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying so save the JSON file Data 'WhitelistedOrigins' in a SQL table however I keep receiving NULL Entries. 
I have used the same method to import attributes into a table and this has worked before although the JSON was formatted differently

JSON

```
"Client": {
"whiteListedOrigins": [
      "file://",
      "https://mobile.gtent.eu",
      "https://mobile.assists.co.uk",
      "https://valueadds3.active.eu",
      "https://flash3.active.eu",
      "https://valueadds3.assists.co.uk"
    ]
}
```

SQL

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\config.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS A

UPDATE dbo.CommonBaseline
SET CommonBaseline.whiteListedOrigins=  whiteListedOrigins
     FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.Client')
        WITH ( 
            whiteListedOrigins Varchar (MAX))
```

RESULT

[image]

Comment: Did you post the exact JSON? It is missing curly brackets at the bginning and end.

Comment: @SalmanA This is just an extract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) with explicit schema and `AS JSON` option in a column definition.

> If you want to return a nested JSON fragment from a JSON property, you
>   have to provide the AS JSON flag. Without this option, if the property
>   can't be found, OPENJSON returns a NULL value instead of the
>   referenced JSON object or array, or it returns a run-time error in
>   strict mode.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @Json nvarchar(max) = N'{
"Client": {
"whiteListedOrigins": [
      "file://",
      "https://mobile.gtent.eu",
      "https://mobile.assists.co.uk",
      "https://valueadds3.active.eu",
      "https://flash3.active.eu",
      "https://valueadds3.assists.co.uk"
    ]
}
}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.Client') WITH ( 
   whiteListedOrigins nvarchar (MAX) AS JSON
)
```

Output:

```
--------------------
whiteListedOrigins
--------------------
[
      "file://",
      "https://mobile.gtent.eu",
      "https://mobile.assists.co.uk",
      "https://valueadds3.active.eu",
      "https://flash3.active.eu",
      "https://valueadds3.assists.co.uk"
    ]
```

Notes:

Your JSON (without surrounding `{` and `}`) is not valid.

Comment: The extra `{}` braces you added are the most important part, though, otherwise you get an SQL Error `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 0.`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, thanks, the answer is updated with this note.

Comment: @Zhorov You have really helped me over the past few days! Thank you.

Comment: @GrahamNorton Glad to help.